# Administrate gem — Pass custom HTML classes into fields

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css, administrate

I use Rails 7, Ruby 2.7, the [administrate gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) for my admin dashboard and [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/) for the frontend.

I am trying to pass custom HTML classes into the fields. I have already [generated the partials](https://administrate-prototype.herokuapp.com/customizing_attribute_partials) for all field types using the command `rails generate administrate:views:field all`.

For example, in `app\views\fields\string\_form`, how could I add to the input field a tailwind class? Below is a part of the generated file.

```
<div class="field-unit__field">
  <%= f.text_field field.attribute %>
</div>
```

The [doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/administrate/Administrate/Field/Base#attribute-instance_method) stipulates that there is an instance method called `html_class` inherited from `Base` but I struggle to apply it to the view.

Something like this would be perfect:

- `field.attribute.html_class("class1 class2 class3")`
- `field.attribute.with_options(html_class: "class1 class2 class3")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woah ok, this was much easier than what I thought. I had to add the classes this way:

```
<div class="field-unit__field">
  <%= f.text_field field.attribute, class: "class1 class2 class3" %>
</div>
```